# Resolve running Flutter repo

Tags: flutter

Can someone help me run this repo https://github.com/sbis04/decifer?

I'm currently working on a Flutter project and using the "file" package version 6.1.2 in my app. When I try to run my Flutter application on an iOS simulator, I encounter an error related to this package.

Here is the error message I receive:

`Error (Xcode): ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/file-6.1.2/lib/src/interface/file.dart:15:16: Error: The method 'File.create' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'File.create'. Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching application on iPhone 14.`
From the error, it appears there's a conflict between the method signatures of File.create in the file package and another part of my code (perhaps another package that is overriding File.create).

Steps I've taken to troubleshoot this issue include trying to upgrade/downgrade the "file" package, and checking for updates on my other packages. However, these attempts haven't resolved the issue.

```
name: deepgram_transcribe
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 2.3.0+24

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.1 <3.0.0"

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  mime: ^1.0.1
  firebase_core: ^1.13.1
  cloud_functions: ^3.2.10
  subtitle: ^0.1.0-beta.3
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.11
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.0.0
  file_picker: ^4.5.1
  cloud_firestore: ^3a.1.10
  firebase_storage: ^10.2.9
  audioplayers: ^4.1.0 
  shimmer: ^2.0.0
  record: ^3.0.3
  tuple: ^2.0.0
  printing: ^5.10.4
  file: ^6.1.0


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
  flutter_launcher_icons:

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/decifer_icon.png"

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/sample_audio.mp3
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: Poppins
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Poppins-Thin.ttf
          weight: 100
        - asset: fonts/Poppins-ExtraLight.ttf
          weight: 200
        - asset: fonts/Poppins-Light.ttf
          weight: 300
        - asset: fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf
          weight: 400
        - asset: fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf
          weight: 500
        - asset: fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf
          weight: 600
        - asset: fonts/Poppins-ExtraBold.ttf
          weight: 700
        - asset: fonts/Poppins-Black.ttf
          weight: 800

  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Could someone please help me understand what might be causing this error and how I could resolve it? Any insight into how method overriding is working in this context would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Version `6.1.2` of the `file` library is known to contain this breaking bug.
This [Github issue](https://github.com/google/file.dart/issues/204) explains the problem. The authors suggest updating to a newer version

Quoted from there

> The issue is that the older package:file versions claim to support SDK 2.19.0, but due to dart-lang/sdk#49647, don't actually support it.

and

> we can mitigate this issue by having the most common consumers of package:file require at least version 6.1.3